# Finding entries in a Set containing a prefix

Tags: java, search, set, prefix

I'm doing a couple of exercises as a Java beginner and I just can't get this to work.

This is what I'm working with:

```
public static Set<Person> prefixName(final Set<Person> persons, final String prefix) {
    ...
}
```

The Set consists of names, while the prefix is a substring of a name (or not). So with `persons = {Larry, Dave, Laura},` `prefix = La`, the method would return `{Larry, Laura}`

I asked a buddy of mine for some help and he said to look into streams. Since the book I'm working with hasn't made any mentions of streams yet, I believe there is an easier and more beginner-friendler solution to it, too!

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664715/finding-entries-in-a-treeset-that-contain-a-prefix) is basically the same problem, but with a TreeSet, which apparently has a pretty handy method for exactly this.

Comment: Did you look at Map implementations?

Comment: I know what a HashMap is, which is also what immediately came to mind. Wouldn't that however require the strings to already be mapped, i.e. having a `key = La` already be mapped to a `value = Larry, Laura`?

Comment: Should a new set be returned or should the old one be modified?

Comment: A new set should be returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general set can **not take advantage** of knowing a **prefix** in order to find elements. You will need to traverse the whole set and check each entry.

A `TreeSet` however **can take advantage** of that knowledge as entries there are **sorted by their prefixes**. In order to find all prefixes you just need to take the whole sub-tree rooted at the prefix, this can be computed fast.

Here is an illustration showing the internal structure of a `TreeSet`:

[image: TreeSet structure]

---

Here is the obvious naive implementation:

```
public static Set<Person> prefixName(final Set<Person> persons, final String prefix) {
    final Set<Person> personsWithPrefix = new HashSet<>();
    for (final Person person : persons) {
        if (person.getName().startsWith(prefix)) {
            personsWithPrefix.add(person);
        }
    }
    return personsWithPrefix;
}
```

Or alternatively a more compact **Java 8** solution using streams:

```
public static Set<Person> prefixName(final Set<Person> persons, final String prefix) {
    return persons.stream()
        .filter(person -> person.getName().startsWith(prefix))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The naive implementation was exactly what I was looking for! Would you mind explaining the second solution as well? Now that you're the second person to recommend streams I'm curious, what does the return-statement do exactly?

Comment: Also: wouldn't it then make more sense to add all the elements of the original into a TreeSet? Wouldn't that be more efficient in the long run?

Comment: The stream essentially does the same, it just looks more compact. It first views the set as `Stream` (it therefore internally uses its `Iterator` and converts it to a `Spliterator`). Then you tell the stream what to do when it traverses the elements. It should **filter out** each element for which the condition resolves to `false` and only continue the iteration for elements where it resolves to `true`. Then it should collect everything in a `Set`. The statement itself now returns something of type `Set`, we directly return it with `return`.

Comment: It would be more effective if the elements previously would be organized in a `TreeSet`, yes. But if you copy everything into a `TreeSet` at the point where you need it, it will not have any benefit, as the adding also needs to traverse **each element** and that is the bottleneck of the performance here.

Comment: Makes sense. The stream looks a lot less intimidating than it did on first glance. And yeah, that's I assumed! Thank you so much for your help as well as for your explanations! Really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad it helped. A big advantage of the stream is that it can **very easy** be parallelized. You just need to call `parallelStream()` instead of `stream()`. The good thing here is that your problem also works perfectly in a *parallel* environment, so you can use it without any further change. The stream then internally will split the iterator of the set in several pieces (that is why it uses the spliterator) and traverse each piece on another core of your CPU. That is also why the iteration order, if using parallel streams, is *not predictable*.